# 80s robot cartoon, I think Japanese, where a boy uses a medallion to call a robot

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, mecha

I'm looking for a show I saw in the 80s as a kid.

It had a boy and a girl, I think they were brother and sister. The boy had a medallion that he used to call the robot, and then he hides it in his chest.

I remember the last episode, the robot fights another robot, which looks like a tiger. He knows he can't win so he takes the kid out and then fights the other robot until they both die.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be [*"Astroganger"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroganger) (アストロガンガー, Astrogangā). It's a series originally aired in Japan in 1972; dubbed versions were broadcast in the following years in many countries.

[image: characters of Astroganga]

The protagonist is Kantaro (or Charlie, in some dubbed versions), the young son of an alien scientist and a human one; when the boy is 10 years old, the same space invaders that destroyed Kantaro's mother's planet, called Blasters, arrive on Earth. Kantaro must defeat them to save the planet, with the help of Astroganger, a sentient robot made of "living metal".

The medallion converts the boy into energy, allowing him to fuse with the robot. The fusion sequence can be seen in this YouTube video of the Italian opening:

The girl is not the boy's sister, but rather a friend of his.

According to [the Italian Wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroganga#Episodi), the last episode is exactly as you remember:

> The Blasters send on an island a space Panther that feeds on vital energy. It quickly absorbs the vital energy of the whole island, killing all local life forms.
> Fearing that the monster they freed on Earth could end up destroying it, the Blasters send both it and Astroganger in space.
> Astroganger fights against the Panther, but notices that it is draining the kids'life. The robot drives the monster toward the Blasters' spaceship, and it kills them all.
> Finally, the robot sends the kid back on Earth and faces the Panther alone, sacrificing himself to save the planet.