70/80's animated movie/series about a boy who finds a silver star which summons a mech suit
The animated film I am looking for is from either the 70's or early 80's.
A boy finds a silver star and when he throws it in the air it summons a mech suit, and they do different tasks that save people. If I remember correctly the robot/mech suit was mainly white with the star on his forehead.
I was really young when watching this so cannot remember much else. I have been searching on the web and cannot find it. I do not think it is a obvious answer.

Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE! This is a bit sparse on detail at the moment, are you sure there's nothing else you recall that you could [edit] in? Do you remember the name of the boy or any details about his appearance? How does he find the star? What colour is the mech suit? Is it an autonomous thing, or does the boy pilot the mech? Was this a hand-drawn animation, or more 3D/computer generated?

Probably Mado King Grandzort?

Hi, thanks for that. Unfortunately that's not it. Just checked out an episode. If I remember correctly the robot/mech suit was mainly white with the star on his forehead

This could possibly be Astroganger (see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267207/40711 where it is the accepted answer). The boy uses a round medallion with a 4-pointed star to summon the robot with which he fuses.

Is this The Ultraman (1979-1980)...?

Jonias (AKA: Joe), a new Ultraman from U-40, merges with young Science Garrison member Chôichirô Hikari to defend the Earth in this, the first-ever animated Ultra Series.


The human protagonist, Choichiro Hikari, places the star-shaped Beam Flasher on his forehead, which causes him to transform into Ultraman Joneus and grow to giant size. Ultraman Joneus has a red and white colour scheme, mostly red, but his head and neck are almost entirely white.
The transformation sequence is shown at the start of the video below.



